# logging-in technique similar to a router?

Tags: authentication

I visited some various websites lately and they use the logging-in techniques that some linksys or belkin home routers use. A small window box opens up asking for username and password. After logging-in everything is normal. Does anybody know how this is done? If so, why isn't the regular technique used (i.e. log-in form in a page similar to gmail, yahoo or most websites)?

Comment: Can you give us an example? I don't know what are you talking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are referring to is http's [basic authentification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), or its marginally more secure version [digest access authentification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)

There's a few reasons it's not used often:

1. It doesn't add any security over form-based login systems, and it uses out-of date technology (the MD5 digest used has been shown to have a number of weaknesses making it inappropriate for security purposes).  Basic auth can actually send passwords in plaintext in the query, which isn't ever encrypted, even under https.
2. It can't be styled to match the website, and can't be customised (i.e. you can't add things like a "forgotten password?" link like you can a form.
3. It doesn't always work with accessibility software such as screen-readers, whereas a form can easily be written so it *always* will.

There are probably other considerations too, but these are just off the top of my head.